# Calculate $\int_{\mathcal{C}(0,3)} \frac{e^{2/z}}{z-2}\,dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

$$\int_{\mathcal{C}(0,3)} \frac{e^{2/z}}{z-2}\,dz$$
Solution approach:
I thought of calculating that problem using the residue theorem, therefore I calculated the residue at $z=2$, which turned out to be equal to $e$ (Wolfram confirmed). However, I am not sure if I should calculate the residue at $z=0$, but I am having problem doing that. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

That pole is enclosed, so yes, we include its residue. In a neighbourhood of $z=0$, the integrand is a Laurent series,$$-\tfrac12(1+\tfrac12z+\tfrac14z^2+\cdots)(1+\tfrac{2}{z}+\tfrac{2}{z^2}+\cdots).$$Since $\tfrac1z=z^n\tfrac{1}{z^{n+1}}$, the $\tfrac1z$ coefficient is$$-\tfrac12\sum_{n\ge0}\left(\tfrac12\right)^n\tfrac{2^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}=-\sum_n\tfrac{1}{(n+1)!}=1-e.$$This makes the integral $2\pi i$. [WA agrees](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+exp%282*exp%28-ix%29%2F3%29%2F%283exp%28ix%29-2%29*3iexp%28ix%29+from+0+to+2*pi), if you know how to ask.

Comment: (+1) for the brute force approach.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to kick the essential singularity $z=0$ out of the contour. That is, substitute $z=2/w$ (to get rid of these $2$'s). Then $dz=-2\,dw/w^2$, and the "$-$" is compensated by the opposite orientation of the resulting contour $|w|=2/3$; choosing the standard orientation instead, $$\oint_{|z|=3}\frac{e^{2/z}}{z-2}\,dz=\oint_{|w|=2/3}\frac{e^w}{w(1-w)}\,dw.$$ Now the only singularity inside is the simple pole at $w=0$, with the residue clearly equal to $1$.

Comment: If anyone disbelieves this inversion works for contour integrals, the substitutions $z=3e^{i\theta},\,w=\tfrac2z=\tfrac23e^{-i\theta}$ verifies it viz.$$\oint_{|z=3|}f(z)dz=\int_0^{2\pi}f(3e^{i\theta})3ie^{i\theta}d\theta=-2\oint_{|w|=2/3}f(2/w)w^{-2}dw,$$which for $f(z):=\tfrac{e^{2/z}}{z-2}$ has RHS $-\oint_{|w|=2/3}\tfrac{e^w}{w(1-w)}dw$.